# What type is useFormik in formik forms?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I created a react formik form that consists of several components. I need pass down the useFormik object to the components of the form. What is the right type for formik?

Parent form

```
 const formik = useFormik({ ...
```

Child component

```
interface IAddressBoxProps {
  skip: () => void
  formik: any
}

const AddressBox: React.FC<IAddressBoxProps> = (props: IAddressBoxProps) => {
  const { skip, formik } = props
 ...
```

Answer (score 26):

When you're unsure of a type, you can use `typeof formik` to get the type for that variable.

The hook signature is

```
useFormik<Values>(config: FormikConfig<Values>): FormikProps<Values>
```

So the return type is `FormikProps` with a generic that depends on the values of your form.

```
import {useFormik, FormikProps} from "formik";

interface MyValues {
    id: number;
}
export const MyComponent = () => {
    const formik: FormikProps<MyValues> = useFormik<MyValues>({});
}
```

[Hook Docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik)

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmAxaJgGsA0cWUOuAClBGCgL5wBmlIcARPdniwNwCwAUP2AA7GGij0AhgGM0cALIBPAGoSANkjQpE-OLrjAAJgC44QpCABGY3nxr80AD0iw4UiEJTxFAYQjh3aCJwALxwABQAlCEAfNp8eq7ungwcuCbEpBRUKAA8iirqmrGhqJipecpqGijRYQg0ETY0QA)

Answer (score 5):

This may be old but your interface can be like this

```
interface IAddressBoxProps {
  skip: () => void
  formik: FormikProps<InitialValuesInterface>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there're some default attributes you need to set.

```
interface OrderStatusFormValues {
  orderNumber: string;
}

const OrderStatusForm = ({ onGetOrderGroups }: OrderStatusFormProps): ReactElement => {
  const { locale, siteId } = useLocale();

  const form: FormikProps<OrderStatusFormValues> = useFormik<OrderStatusFormValues>({
    initialValues: { orderNumber: '' },
    onSubmit: () => {}
  });
```